# Mongo: find subdocument without dot notation

Tags: mongodb

For example we have collection

```
{field: {subfield: 'name'}}
{field: {subfield: 'phone'}}
```

Can I find document without dot notation? Like this

```
db.test.find({field: {subfield: /regex/}})
```

or maybe like this

```
db.test.find({field: {$someOperator: {subfield: /regex/}}})
```

I just don't want to build dot notation like

```
db.test.find({"field.subfield": /regex/})
```

Comment: why don't you want to use dot notation?

Comment: for example when I submit form on web I need to build dot notation query instead of just use submitted object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
db.test.find({field: {$someOperator: {subfield: /regex/}}})
```

Is actually another way of querying in MongoDB which uses object euqality to search for subdocuments.

So no, you must use dot notation unless you were searching for where one object exactly equals the other.

That being said you could wrap the document in `$elemMatch`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/ that would work

#### Edit

Considering you collection structure `$elemMatch` won't actually work.

Comment: you can't use $elemMatch unless it's an array - plain embedded documents won't match like you expect.  Did you actually try it out?

Comment: @GabeRainbow there is a JIRA to have this changed by default somewhere, however, object comparison does have its uses

Comment: imho, this is a flaw in mongo. it calls for the $eq operator. for example, the similar greater than $gte will provide your results plus unwanted results. db.test.find({field: {$gte: {subfield: "test"}}}) while the desired one is  db.test.find({field: {$eq: {subfield: "test"}}})

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using an aggregation pipeline.

First, use $replaceRoot to move the root document to the subdocument. Also, retain the root document ($$ROOT) in a field so that you can output it later.

```
$replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [{
                _root: "$$ROOT"
            },
            "$field"
        ]
    }
}
```

Next, use $match to perform your query on the subdocument.

```
$match: {
    subfield: /regex/
}
```

Finally, use $replaceRoot to set the root back to the whole document.

```
$replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: "$_root"
}
```

I don't think this would be very performant, but it works.