# PyMongo query with regex returns nothing despite if: elif: else

Tags: regex, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

For some odd reason, I have a Mongo query that returns literally nothing (blank line with no data) despite using what seems like a condition that could not possibly be escaped. To reproduce (assuming you have PyMongo installed):

```
import pymongo
import re

manyNodesDeep = {
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": {
                "four": {
                    "five": "five"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
fooBar = {
    "foo": "bar"
}

with pymongo.MongoClient() as conn:
    db = conn[u'local']

    collection = db.my_collection
    print "Collection: {}".format(collection)

    # clear collection
    collection.remove()

    collection.insert(manyNodesDeep)
    collection.insert(fooBar)

    # returns manyNodesDeep and fooBar objects:
    print "print node in collection.find():"
    for node in collection.find():
        print node

    # returns manyNodesDeep object:
    print "print node in collection.find() exact query"
    for node in collection.find({"one": {"two": {"three": {"four": {"five": "five"}}}}}):
        if node:
            print node
        else:
            print "no luck"

    # returns nothing at all:
    print "print node in collection.find() RegEx query"
    for node in collection.find({"one": {"two": {"three": {"four": {"five": re.compile("five", re.IGNORECASE)}}}}}):
        if node:
            print "regex: " + node
            print node
            print "TEST1"
        elif not node:
            print "regex: failed 1st if"
            print "TEST2"
        else:
            print "regex: failed both ifs"
            print "TEST3"
```

I would have expected for the last statement to print *something*, even if that something is `None`. But none of it actually prints at all... Output:

> ```
> Collection: Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'local'), u'my_collection')
> print node in collection.find():
> {u'_id': ObjectId('55f39829e9e17246af559b5d'), u'one': {u'two': {u'three': {u'four': {u'five': u'five'}}}}}
> {u'_id': ObjectId('55f39829e9e17246af559b5e'), u'foo': u'bar'}
> print node in collection.find() exact query
> {u'_id': ObjectId('55f39829e9e17246af559b5d'), u'one': {u'two': {u'three': {u'four': {u'five': u'five'}}}}}
> print node in collection.find() RegEx query
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

#### Edit:

It was also suggested to me to try like this:

```
for node in collection.find({"one": {"two": {"three": {"four": {"five": {"$regex": "five"}}}}}}):
    # ...
```

But unfortunately, the output is identical...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the *dot notation* in case of regular expression match:

```
collection.find({"one.two.three.four.five": re.compile(r"five")})
```

With ignore case:

```
collection.find({"one.two.three.four.five": re.compile(r"FIVE", re.IGNORECASE)})
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16105447/771848).

Comment: Oh wow, nice find. This is so odd (and nowhere to be found in documentation, it seems). Thanks so much!