# Find multiple fields without dot notation

Tags: mongodb

I would like to find mongoDB documents where the customer fields match my criteria.

I can do the following, which works well:

```
collection.find({"customer.first_name": "Barack", "customer.last_name": "Obama"}).
```

But how can I do the same query with `customer` as the key of the query ?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
collection.find({"customer": {"first_name": "Barack", "last_name": "Obama"}})
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104499/mongo-find-subdocument-without-dot-notation

Comment: It wouldn't be possible because of another concept of `$elemMatch` [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/]

Comment: Does the `customer` field is an array field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, the answer is **I cannot do that**. The following request

```
collection.find({"customer": {"first_name": "Barack", "last_name": "Obama"}})
```

will match customers being exactly equal to `{"first_name": "Barack", "last_name": "Obama"}`, without any other fields.